# Why do we increase weights of misclassified points in boosting?

Tags: variance, bias, boosting, adaboost

I was reading this [pdf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs578/2005fa/CS578.bagging.boosting.lecture.pdf) and at slide at 23 I got stuck. 
Also how does boosting reduces the bias ? I understand it will reduce variance by averaging.

Comment: The weight is increased on misclassified data points is to ensure that in the next iterations the algorithm will try "harder" to fit them.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs I am not able to understand how algorithm tries "harder". Could you please explain this ?

Comment: More weight is put on those examples to fit the training objective.